# Angular router guard with Observable does not work after page refresh

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing, ngrx, angular-guards

I have the next Angular Guard:

```js
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly userService: UserService
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

      return this.userService.getUserRoles().pipe(
        map(roles => {
          if (roles.admin) {
            return true
          }

          this.router.navigate(['/'])
          return false
        })
      )
  }
}
```

This is method from the service, which return Observable:

```js
  public getUserRoles(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select('user'),
      map(({ roles }) => roles)
    )
  }
```

And this is works when I navigate between page, but when I directly enter in URL some route, for example 'myapp.com/admin', it returns false automatically and the guard does not work. How to make it work properly?

Comment: i think you've lost the store data after refresh , are you saving the store in localstorage or not?

Comment: @FatehMohamed Im not sure this is a good idea save user roles to localstorage. User can just open and localstorage in browser, and he can change admin role to true and then use admin-panel.

Comment: sometimes you have too in case of refresh, using https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk SPA's run in the browser. They are inherently insecure; users can always change the code  and data in the browser to do what they want. The only thing you can secure is the backend. You should check user authorization when they submit changes to the server, and not  worry about a user hacking the local store; just think of it as convenient UI to show what actions they *should* be able to do against the backend. If a user thwarts local settings to view the admin panel, this should not compromise back end security.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess, when entering the url directly in the browser, you are restarting your application and the store is reset to defaults with no user.

You should rewrite your `getUserRoles()` method to check if the user has been authenticated before reading roles, and not just read store state. If you are using OAuth2, for example, this would redirect the user to your authentication endpoint passing appropriate state to resume on the `myapp.com/admin` route once re-authentication handshake is complete and the store is populated.

The specifics of this will very much depend on what authentication approach you are using.